# how to listen for event in child component update parent UI Astro file client side

Tags: javascript, event-handling, svelte, astrojs

I have a Parent Astro page, where i have a svelete component.
i wanna Update some UI on the parent astro page when a button gets clicked in the child svelete component

### Parent.astro

```
<script>
    function updateBtn(){
        //Display Button
    }
</script>
<div>
    <div>
        <Scomponent onclick="updateBtn()"/>
    </div>
    <button style="display=none">Click</button>
</div>
```

### Scomponent.svelete (Svelete Component)

```
<div>
    <button>Svelete button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that Astro components only are executed on the server. On the client (browser), only the framework (i.e. Svelte) component code is executed.

From [Astro docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/framework-components/#passing-props-to-framework-components):

> You can pass a function as a prop to a framework component, but it only works during server rendering. If you try to use the function in a hydrated component (for example, as an event handler), an error will occur.
>
> This is because functions can’t be serialized (transferred from the server to the client) by Astro.

Depending on what exactly you need to do, you should either wrap everything into one Svelte island, or hook up some form of [communication between islands](https://docs.astro.build/en/recipes/sharing-state-islands/).

Comment: i know and understand that astro components only are executed on the server and all i wanted was a work around, which i luckily found out myself.i could embrace event bubling and check if the the target was the one i wanted